# Sticky Header -  body position relative to the Dynamic header length

Tags: javascript, css, sticky

Trying to get the header to stick to the top of the page - `postion:fixed` - works

But on doing this the body cannot be placed relative to the header - which is possible if `position:relative` [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/waBxU/2/)

What i'm trying to achieve -

- A Sticky header which moves along with scroll
- A body which is at relative height from the above header( who's height is dynamic )

What I have done so far : [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BGr97/1/)

I'm a trying to find a **Pure CSS**( is it even possible? ) solution,but have been unsuccessful at it - any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `padding-top: XXX` to the body wrapper div, where XXX is equal to the header height. In order to do it (have fixed header and scrollable body) with pure CSS you have to know the header height upfront. Otherwise it will cover the top part of the body div.

Comment: tried that - only works if the header is fixed - check the demo - `onfocus` the header height is changing.Putting a margin will not change bring the body down..

Comment: @VivekChandra Yes - this solution works when header height is known upfront. Unfortunately I cannot see a CSS-only solution when the header height is changing. You might need to use some JS to achieve that.